# Terraform: can't connect to AWS provider using shared config file or static variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to use terraform to manage AWS resources and trying to set up the credentials configuration. I'm following the official documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html

My first idea was set a shared credentials file so I configure it:

- ~.aws/credentials

  ```
  [default]
  aws_access_key_id=****
  aws_secret_access_key=****
  ```
- ~.aws/config

  ```
  [default]
  region=us-east-1
  output=json
  ```
- app/main.tf

  ```
  provider "aws" {
      region = "us-east-1"
      version = "~> 2.0"
      profile = "default"
  }

  terraform {
      backend "s3" {
          bucket = "example-bucket"
          key    = "terraform-test.tfstate"
          region = "us-east-1"
    }
  }
  ```

When I run `terraform init` I receive the following message:

```
Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
        Please see https://terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/index.html for more information on
        providing credentials for the AWS Provider
```

I have already tested the credentials using aws cli and it's working perfectly.

After that, I tried to configure static credentials in main.tf like this:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
    version = "~> 2.0"
    profile = "default"
    access_key = "****"
    secret_key = "****"
}
```

Same error...

I decided to test with environment variables and then it worked. But now I want to know why I could not configure with static variables or shared config file. All this cases was described in the official docs, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing different that I'm seeing is the ~.aws/config, my config is in this way

~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ****
aws_secret_access_key = ****
region = us-east-2
```

Whit this config above terraform just need the

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
    version = "~> 2.0"
}
```

In the other hand you can put everything on the provider like this

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
    version = "~> 2.0"
    access_key = "****"
    secret_key = "****"
}
```

By the way `backend` will not work for the first time so comment that run a `terraform init`, after the proveider was downloaded uncomment backup and run a terraform init again.. If the error continue please informe the terraform version.